# AVD uncompatable with Android 4.3

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

I tried running my Simple Music Player application but got an error "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.3'"

Audio file is in raw file under res and it is in mp3 format

Comment: Which ADT plug in are you using??

Answer (score 0):

Please Check minsdk version and targetsdk version in your Manifest file .it it compatible wtih 4.3 or not?
Create your emulator with AVD Manager and also check your application's minSdkVersion like this: android:minSdkVersion="8" for an example my app targets with Android 2.2 which is having an api level 8. So create emulator targeting Android 2.3.

Comment: minsdk is 8 and targetsdk is 17 but i don't know what value is actually required

Comment: I followed what you just recommended to create emulator with AVD.But when i ran my program it generated an error saying Unable to install my prog.apk and showed a null